# Issue accessing the table data structure in Ballerina. error invalid operation... does not support field access for non required field

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I've been learning Ballerina and have been going through the examples. I'm facing an issue with the following example on the documentation in [Ballerina By Example - Tables](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/table.html) .

The code in the example (and mine) is below:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/jsonutils;
import ballerina/xmlutils;

type Employee record {
    int id;
    string name;
    float salary;
};

public function main() {

    table<Employee> tbEmployee = table {
        {key id, name, salary},
        [
            {1, "Mary", 300.5},
            {2, "John", 200.5},
            {3, "Jim", 330.5}
        ]
    };

    io:print("Table Information: ");
    io:println(tbEmployee);

    Employee e1 = {id: 1, name: "Jane", salary: 300.50};
    Employee e2 = {id: 2, name: "Anne", salary: 100.50};
    Employee e3 = {id: 3, name: "John", salary: 400.50};
    Employee e4 = {id: 4, name: "Peter", salary: 150.0};

    table<Employee> tb = table {
        {key id, name, salary},
        [
            e1,
            e2
        ]
    };

    Employee[] employees = [e3, e4];

    foreach var emp in employees {
        var ret = tb.add(emp);
        if (ret is ()) {
            io:println("Adding record to table successful");
        } else {
            io:println("Adding to table failed: ", ret.reason());
        }
    }

    io:println("Table Information: ", tb);

    io:println("Using foreach: ");
    foreach var x in tb {
        io:println("Name: ", x.name);
    }

    io:println("Using while loop: ");
    while (tb.hasNext()) {
        var ret = tb.getNext();
        io:println("Name: ", ret.name);
    }

    json retValJson = jsonutils:fromTable(tb);
    io:println("JSON: ", retValJson.toJsonString());

    xml retValXml = xmlutils:fromTable(tb);
    io:println("XML: ", retValXml);

    int|error count = tb.remove(isHigherSalary);
    io:println("Deleted Count: ", count);

    io:println(tb);
}

function isHigherSalary(Employee emp) returns boolean {
    return emp.salary > 300.0;
}
```

When I run it, I get an issue with the following line (59):

`io:println("Name: ", ret.name);`

```
error: .::tables_orig.bal:59:30: invalid operation: type 'record {| anydata...; |}' does not support field access for non-required field 'name'
```

I am using Ballerina 1.0.5. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using Ballerina 1.0.5 and the code on the website was for 1.1.0 which just released on December 19, 2019 and the website had a bug where the code/section doesn't change when you change the version number from the dropdown and go to the previous versions.

The syntax in the example listed on the [Ballerina By Example website](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/table.html) isn't backwards compatible for previous versions prior to 1.1.0. The code worked in 1.0.5 when I changed `ret.name` to `ret.get("name")`:

```
while (tb.hasNext()) {
        var ret = tb.getNext();
        io:println("Name: ", ret.get("name")); // changed from ret.name in the example
    }
```

It was confusing to me because in the previous `foreach` loop it worked when `ret.name` is called i.e.

```
io:println("Using foreach: ");
foreach var x in tb {
    io:println(typeof tb);
    io:println("Name: ", x.name); // this works
}
```

### Reason For The Error

It becomes evident after you check the type of the variable `ret` in both loops by using `typeof` :

```
io:println("Using foreach: ");
    foreach var x in tb {
        io:println("Type of tb is : ", typeof tb);
        io:println("Name: ", x.name); 
        break;
    }

    io:println("Using while loop: ");
    while (tb.hasNext()) {
        var ret = tb.getNext();
        io:println("Type of var ret = tb.getNext() is : ", typeof ret);
        io:println("Name: ", ret.get("name"));
        break;
    }
```

Output:

```
Using foreach: 
Type of tb is : typedesc table<Employee>
Name: Jane
Using while loop: 
Type of var ret = tb.getNext() is : typedesc Employee
Name: John
```

Field access is supported when it is of type `table` like in the foreach loop but it didn't work because the type of `ret` was `Employee` that we defined earlier.

I hope this helps someone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, field access should have worked with `getNext()`, but there was an issue with how the type was decided for the `getNext()` invocation. This has now been fixed with https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/commit/8196d93023ba12958dfdd5f28a70c8da2147bf48, and the fix will be available with Ballerina 1.1.0, which will be released soon.

Comment: Thanks! I tried pretty much everything I could think of to get this to work. It feels a little better knowing that it is a version issue.